# can't get facebook access_token

Tags: facebook, access-token

here is my code:

```
<?php require_once './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '333...',
'secret' => '6da64...', )); $access_token = $facebook->GetAccessToken();
var_dump($access_token);  ?>

output:
333...|6da64...
```

I'm using facebook-php-sdk-v3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The function is getAccessToken not GetAccessToken (see FB documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/ )

Decapitalize the "G" and give that a try.